# Command Not Found Error on Discord.py bot

Tags: discord.py

Application Error Command Not Found im new to this and im trying to start something a bit huge, but the bot is the hardest part what is wrong everything here is listed and written correctly

````py
> 
> @bot.command(
>     name="order",
>     description= " --Here are Somethings to note!\n --Before Placing your Order Ensure you know what you want\n --When Processing your
> Order it is Required for Users to Pay 1/4 of the Offered --Amount as a
> Starting Fee and to Keep Business Growing \n --User is also
> Responsible for the OutCome of their Order \n Please be as Detailed as
> Possible and Provide References and Models as we DO NOT provide those
> \n Would you like to Proceed?",
>     scope= 991484473139007588, ) async def order(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
>     await ctx.send("Hello")
> 
> bot.run(DiscordToken)
> ```
````

Comment: Please format the code properly - what's the full error traceback and what did you actually send in discord to make it fail?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Context
```

I've formated the code...

```py
description="--Here are Somethings to note!\n --Before Placing your Order Ensure you know what you want\n --When Processing your Order it is Required for Users to Pay 1/4 of the Offered --Amount as a Starting Fee and to Keep Business Growing \n --User is also Responsible for the OutCome of their Order \n Please be as Detailed as Possible and Provide References and Models as we DO NOT provide those\n Would you like to Proceed?"
@bot.command(name="order", description=description, scope=991484473139007588)
async def order(ctx:Context):
    await ctx.send("Hello")

bot.run(DiscordToken)
```

What exacly was the Error message? Do you use `async def on_message()`?